# Python Selenium 'clicks' element but nothing happens

Tags: python, selenium

So I am trying to scrape a website, and I want to click an element, go to the page that opens from the click, find another element and click that one. The first click seems to work, no errors, but the next page doesn't open, thus I get an error. Here is a screenshot of what I want to click on the fist page: https://prnt.sc/10l8xa4. Clicking that should redirect to the second page. The problem seems to be that the driver clicks the element but nothing happens:

```
import sys, csv, os
from selenium import webdriver  # Selenium 3.141.0
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep



class Scraper(object):
    ''' A lot of the messy code is just playing with the tags from the page'''

    def __init__(self, link):
        self.link = link
        self.driver = self.configure_driver()  # The simulated browser

        # Configuring the browser simulator, named driver, that will get all the information
    def configure_driver(self):
        # Add additional Options to the webdriver
        chrome_options = Options()
        # add the argument and make the browser Headless. It will work smoother& faster but it will miss the first category
        # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options)
        return driver

    def click_element(self, selector):  # Clicks the provided element from the page, even if not visible
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector)))
        ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    product_link = 'https://www.action.com/nl-nl/click-and-collect-producten/'  # An example of a product
    app = Scraper(product_link)
    with app.driver:
        app.driver.get(product_link)
        app.click_element('a.content-card.has-text.card-theme--light.card-size--s.card-align--bottom-left')  # This gets clicked and should open new page, but it doesn't
        sleep(10)
        app.click_element('a.product-card__link')  # This throws a Timeout, because the element can't be found, which is obvoius because the second page(which has this element) didn't open
        sleep(20)
```

Comment: Selenium clicks using a mouse, not using a button. So if there is something on top of the button it won't click. Check if there's an Ad Pop Up or something. Or it could be that you're clicking on an old element that no longer exists.

Comment: There are no pop-ups. The webdriver just 'stares' at the <a> tag and doesnt click it, then the error appears

Comment: May you provide screenshot, what actually are you going to click, seems like that element is not visible yet

Comment: @MercifulSory I see, you need to click "Thema's" button first, to open pop-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try use like that:

```
with app.driver:
    app.driver.get(product_link)
    sleep(2)
    app.click_element('li.has-submenu')
    sleep(2)
    app.click_element(
        'div.grid-item.grid-item--content')  # This gets clicked and should open new page, but it doesn't
    sleep(2)
```

you should add step of openning pop-up and then click on your aimed button

Code with required argument but, by xpath:

```
    def click_element(self, selector, by=By.CSS_SELECTOR):  # Clicks the provided element from the page, even if not visible
        element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((by, selector)))
        ActionChains(self.driver).move_to_element(element).click(element).perform()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    product_link = 'https://www.action.com/nl-nl/click-and-collect-producten/'  # An example of a product
    app = Scraper(product_link)
    with app.driver:
        app.driver.get(product_link)
        sleep(2)
        app.click_element("//section[@class='grid']/div[@class='grid-item grid-item--content'][1]", By.XPATH)
        sleep(2)
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't scrape what I intended..

Comment: @MercifulSory I got it, try the code snipped, that I've just added

Comment: @MercifulSory the elements what you're trying to get isn't unique and better to get them by numbers or use XPATH. I added opportunity to use different type of selectors to click_element def

Comment: One more question, if possible, what do I do if I want all the categories, instead of only the first one??

Comment: @MercifulSory you mean, like: 'Decoratie', 'Dieren' etc?change number of `'grid-item grid-item--content'`, adding +1
`//section[@class='grid']/div[@class='grid-item grid-item--content'][2]`
or
you can use `contains(text(),'')` feature of `xpath` and make your selectors more unique changing only text value like that:
`//span[contains(text(),'Decoratie')]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229886/discussion-between-vova-and-mercifulsory).